# integrate Marketing Cloud with an app and send Mobile push notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobileconnect

We have our custom Company app and we want to send push notifications from the marketing cloud to that app, using MobilePush feature. What is the best expertise here? Is it recommended to create a MC dev environment for that or the risks of breaking anything in the MC from an App are pretty low?

I am very confuse about the release : the Marketing Cloud Engagement mobile app will be retired on May 5, 2024. Will it affect such an integration